# Leaving some {template} in builder URI with UriBuilder

Tags: java, jersey, uri, jax-rs

Jersey UriBuilder can replace all the templates in a URI:

```
UriBuilder.fromResource(this.getClass()).path("{id}/{op}").build(12, "buy")
```

On the client side, it is exactly what we want ; On the server side, in some cases, we want to keep some templates unchanged (to inform the client that the URI depends on it, that it will have to fill it with values).

Building a URI without giving all template throws an exception. So, is there another way to leave some template unchanged?

Comment: What happens if you supply a string that's the same as the template as a parameter? e.g., `"{id}"` for the first argument to `build()` in your sample code. (I don't know the answer; it depends on how the check for a complete URI is done, I don't want to read the code and don't have Jersey installed.)

Comment: Well tried ;). It replaces `{` and `}` by `%7B` and `%7D`.

Comment: It works! `UriBuilder` returns a `URI`; `toString()` made those `%7`, `getPath()` kept `{`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the proper way to do this is to call #toTemplate. This creates a template string. I believe that a URI that has unresolved template parameters is not valid. Here's an example:

```
UriBuilder.fromResource(this.getClass()).path("{id}/{op}").toTemplate();
```

This will preserve the template place holders.